# How to use addCursorRect outside a NSView?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a menu bar app and I would like when the icon is pressed, the mouse cursor image to change to a custom `NSImage`, but my app does not have a `NSWindow`, it works just from the menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `NSCursor`, which can do what you're looking for. Create a cursor with `NSCursor(image:hotSpot:)`, then use `push()` to set it, and `pop()` to change it back to what it was.